# How to go iterate through a DXF File and look at all the layers? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, dxf

I am currently using netDXF for C# to iterate through a DXF File and look at the layers. However, when iterating through this file, I am getting 5 layers, when in fact there should be 3. Here is the code.

```
{
    doc = new DxfDocument();
    s = (string)RouteData.Values["pathName"];
    doc = DxfDocument.Load((string)RouteData.Values["pathName"]);

    fileExist = System.IO.File.Exists(s);

    if (doc == null)
    {
        PathFlow = 4;
    }
    else if (doc != null)
    {                  
        PathFlow = 3;
        foreach (var layer in doc.Layers)
        {
            a.Add(layer.Name);
            b.Add(layer.ToString());
            c.Add(layer.Handle);
            d++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am writing in c#. Sorry if this is a bad question. But I guess what I am asking is, how am I getting 5 layers, when in fact there should only be 3. I am confused and feel overwhelmed, I can provide more details later. One goal from this is to find the layer names, but I am not sure what to do to get that.

Comment: Can you: 1. List the layers in your question and indicate which 2 are extra for us? 2. Supply a link to the DXF file, maybe with PasteBin?

Comment: Do you rely on `d` counter? so If you call `doc.Layers.Count` what do you get?, It'd be better to upload the `.dxf` file and share it with us..